# jQuery on an img to show a div

Tags: jquery, html

The following code should allow a div to display when the img is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#mob-search-image img').click(function(){
       $('#mobile-search').show();
   });

});

<div id="search">
   <img id="mob-search-image" src="assets/images/mobile-search.png"/> 
</div>
```

Nothing is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$('#mob-search-image img')` to `$("#mob-search-image");`

```
$('#mob-search-image').click(function(){
       $('#mobile-search').show();
   });
```

Comment: `#mob-search-image` is enough and better

Comment: @roasted why is it better?

Comment: @Luke Because using internally `getElementById`

Comment: @Luke because any type of element that has id of "mob-search-image" will trigger this function. In case you want to make sure only img tag with that id should run, use img#mob-search-image.

Comment: @NikolaR. no, only the first one but as IDs must be unique on context page, ID selector must select only one element so no need to filter it by type

Comment: @roasted I understand what you are saying but img#mob-search-image is more specific.

Comment: @NikolaR. there is nothing more specific than using ID selector on valid HTML, otherwise this meaning HTML is not valid and anyway as the value of ID can let suppose it, if duplicate element with same ID exists, big chance it is an image too

Comment: I think it is better now ;)

Comment: I was not talking about duplicate IDs. Lets say you have `<div id="some"></div>`, with using of `$("#some")...` that div could be any other element (ofc with no duplicate ids) but if we use `$("div#some")`, it will be working only for DIV element that has that ID, not some image, span or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mob-search-image').click(function(){
   $('#mobile-search').show();
});
```

- `mob-search-image` is the ID of the image.
- It does not have any `img` child inside it.
- Hence, your code with selector `#mob-search-image img` won't work.